# How to access a property in an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How are you able to print all of the properties for objects in an array.

For example I have this array

```
const todo = [
  {
    text: "Water the plants",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: "Feed the dog",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    text: "Cook dinner",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: "Wash the dishes",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    text: "Clean the house",
    completed: false
  }
];
```

Am I able to print/access all of the text properties at the same time.

For example - if I use

```
console.log(todo.text)
```

I am given undefined? Are you not able to select all of these at the same time?

Comment: I would recommend reading up on [for..in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [indexed collections (arrays)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the array

```
const textArray = todo.map(item => item.text)
```